# SVM in Python Error in fitting dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, linear-regression

I'm rather new to the whole SVM and dataset thing. I did a lot of research but I can't figure out what the problem is.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm

boston = datasets.load_boston()

X, y = boston.data, boston.target
clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100.)
clf.fit(X, y)

clf.predict()
```

I wanted to get it to predict new values but I'm not really sure how to go about that. Furthermore I am getting this error when I'm just trying to fit it.

ValueError: Unknown label type: array([ 24. ,  21.6,  34.7,  33.4,  36.2,  28.7,  22.9,  27.1,  16.5,
        18.9,  15. ,  18.9,  21.7,  20.4,  18.2,  19.9,  23.1,  17.5.....
followed by an array of alot of numbers.

I've been able to use these functions with small arrays that I made to serve as "datasets" for testing.

How do I use SVM to predict new data for this dataset? I also don't have much of an understanding of all this.

Basically what I'm trying to do is take the dataset from boston and predict new data for it. The task given to me was to demonstrate data modeling and prediction using SVM and deliver a test set and a training set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target in Boston dataset is continuous. You are using svm.SVC, which is a classification algorithm (Support Vector Classification). You can do a regression with svm.SVR on this dataset.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm

boston = datasets.load_boston()

X, y = boston.data, boston.target
reg = svm.SVR(gamma=0.001, C=100.)
reg.fit(X, y)

predictions_training_set = reg.predict(X)
```

The `predict` function of any algorithm will accept a parameter, the dataset (X) on which to make the predictions. In the above code I used the training set for that. Normally you would need to perform a training-test split. The `cross_validation.training_test_split` function is handy.
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html

Comment: Oh great! Thanks. So I print(predictions_training_set). What does that array that was printed out represent? Are those the new values that were predicted? If they are how do I only predict a certain number of new values? Sorry about all the questions, this is all very new to me.